# Problem on navbar menu " <a href=#></a> " redirect to /#

Tags: angular

I have a problem the first time when i visit the page the href=# works perfectly but the second time it redirect me to myproject/#
that is not exist on my project should I replace it with something else, By the way I tried to remove href=# but it didn't work.Thanks !

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu tree" data-widget="tree">
<li class="treeview">

          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
            <span>Les employés</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
              </span>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
              <li>
                  <a [routerLink]= "['/emplist']">
                    <i class="fa fa-users"></i> <span>Les employés</span>
                  </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a [routerLink]= "['/empform']">
                    <i class="fa fa-bed"></i> <span>Les congés des employés</span>
                  </a>
              </li>            
          </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

no error

Comment: Can you please post some of your code??

Comment: yes i just posted it

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do by using `<a href="#">` are you trying to go back to your home page?? If so you'll need to use a `[routerLink]` and explicitly set the page

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to redirect you at all, you can do something like this:

**.html**

```
<a href="#" (click)="preventRedirect($event)">
...
</a>
```

**.ts**

```
preventRedirect(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to redirect you can remove href from anchor tag

so you have to change

```
<a href="#">...</a>
```

to

```
<a>...</a>
```

Comment: is not recommand to do it for accessibility concern, on this case, you probably want to remove the a tag

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem ! I used the two previous solutions it works when I navigate to the second page using "routerlink" it works but when I want to go back to the first page the menu "les employés" doesn't want to dropdown ! this is my problem but I solved it by deleting href=#  and I used href="/firstpage" href="/secondpage" to navigate between page instead of routerlink ! Thank you guys !

This is my code it works perfectly but the page should refresh :

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu tree" data-widget="tree">
<li class="treeview">

          <a>
            <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
            <span>Les employés</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
              </span>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
              <li>
                  <a href= "emplist">
                    <i class="fa fa-users"></i> <span>Les employés</span>
                  </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href= "/empform">
                    <i class="fa fa-bed"></i> <span>Les congés des employés</span>
                  </a>
              </li>            
          </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your support !